# Is there any Agile User Story applications for OS X?

Tags: macos, agile, user-stories

Does anyone know of any software that can be used to create Agile User Stories instead of doing it manually with 3M Sticky Notes.  I'm trying to be more Green and a good application that I can used to collect the user stories and then create a nice document to hand to the client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stickies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stickies)? Seriously, though, I'd use a personal wiki or outlining application, like [OmniOutliner](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnioutliner/).

Comment: Yeah I've used a wiki in the past but I was wondering if there was anything out there that someone has developed to handle this specific task!  Maybe there is an opportunity to build such a product!  :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly simple application called Storyboard available [here](http://code.google.com/p/storyboard-agile/). It allows adding stories, editing phases but no printing. Just a simple database.